# Hibernate/JDBC hanging when connecting top PostgreSQL 9.3.1 on Amazon RDS

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, amazon-rds

Last thing shown in logs is :

```
2013-12-01 19:40:00,454 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - Database ->
       name : PostgreSQL
    version : 9.3.1
      major : 9
      minor : 3
2013-12-01 19:40:00,454 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL Native Driver
    version : PostgreSQL 9.3 JDBC4 (build 1100)
      major : 9
      minor : 3
```

I am able to connect to the same endpoint in pgAdmin 3. It will just hang here until Tomcat times out.

Comment: I've tried a different connection pool (Tomcat 7 pool was being used before, I used spring's placeholder pool), still a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using this property:

```
  <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
```

Comment: What dependencies are needed to use this hibernate dialect? I a facing the same problem

Comment: Hi, try using 

<prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>

As well. I forgot to include this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem! I didn't even need change the hibernate dialect.